# How better perform Pearson R from 2 arrays of dimensions (m, n) and (n), returning an array of (m) size? [Python, NumPy, SciPy]

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to improve a simple algorithm to obtaining the Pearson correlation coefficient from two arrays, **X(m, n)** and **Y(n)**, returning me another array **R** of dimension **(m)**.
In the case, I want to know the behavior each row of **X** regarding the values of **Y**. A sample (working) code is presented below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

np.random.seed(1)
m, n = 10, 5

x = 100*np.random.rand(m, n)
y = 2 + 2*x.mean(0)
r = np.empty(m)

for i in range(m):
    r[i] = pearsonr(x[i], y)[0]
```

For this particular case, I get: `r = array([0.95272843, -0.69134753, 0.36419159, 0.27467137, 0.76887201, 0.08823868, -0.72608421, -0.01224453, 0.58375626, 0.87442889])`

For small values of **m** (near 10k) this runs pretty fast, but I'm starting to work with **m ~ 30k**, and so this is taking much longer than I expected. I'm aware I could implement multiprocessing/multi-threading but I believe there's a (better) *pythonic* way of doing this.

I tried to use use `pearsonr(x, np.ones((m, n))*y)`, but it returns only `(nan, nan)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pearsonr` only supports 1D array internally. Moreover, it computes the p-values which is not used here. Thus, it would be more efficient not to compute it if possible. Additionally, the code also recompute the `y` vector every time and it does not efficiently make use of vectorized Numpy operations. This is why the computation is a bit slow. You can check this in the code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L3900-L4117).

One way to compute this is by writing your own custom implementation based on the one of Scipy:

```py
def multi_pearsonr(x, y):
    xmean = x.mean(axis=1)
    ymean = y.mean()
    xm = x - xmean[:,None]
    ym = y - ymean
    normxm = np.linalg.norm(xm, axis=1)
    normym = np.linalg.norm(ym)
    return np.clip(np.dot(xm/normxm[:,None], ym/normym), -1.0, 1.0)
```

It is **450 times faster** on my machine for m = 10_000.

Note that I did not keep the checks of the Scipy code, but it may be a good idea to keep them if your input is not guaranteed to be statistically safe (ie. well formatted for the computation of the Pearson test).

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! I never thought about looking into SciPy `pearsonr` code, but it makes sense as I am not interested in the _p-value_, so just by avoiding this calculation it is possible to gain a lot of performance. I'll follow your tip and add some data check before running the **multi_pearson** function.